# Python 2.7 on Samsung ChromeBook

Tags: chrome-os, chrome-book

I notice that there is a `/usr/bin/python` which is symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` on Samsung Chromebook (`GOOGLE_RELEASE=4319.79.0`).  But there is no file there and hence the directory entries show up in red.

Is there some way of installing / activating Python?

Comment: Chrome OS isn't really UNIX, flagging as off-topic

Comment: Really? It is described as [Linux-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_os)...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84160/running-python-on-chromeos

Comment: @jasonwryan By the same vein, should we allow Android questions too? (I know, the fact that there's already an SE site for that affects Android's suitability here; but even if there wasn't a dedicated site, consider whether Android questions would be accepted.)