# How do Install Python to run in Linux

Tags: linux, python, xfce

I recently installed xfce4 on my Dell Chromebook, through the crouton project. so I could run more programs on it. And possibly start to try some programming. I heard about Python but there isn't a lot of help on how to actually get it for xfce4. Also if you possibly could suggest a better version of Linux to use with Python that would be great too.

Comment: xfce4 is just a desktop environment - I'd be surprised if python was not already installed as part of the underlying Crouton OS (since it's Debian-based IIRC) - did you actually try it?

Comment: It has Python (v2.7) installed but I am unaware of how to access it. the only way I can see it is if I right click on a file on my Desktop and choose the option "open in other system". but it still won't do anything at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `python -V` in a terminal and see if there is any version pre-installed. If not, use one of the methods described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84160/running-python-on-chromeos). My suggestion though, would be to consider using another Linux distro than Chrome OS. And not just because of this Python thing. You could try Ubuntu if you are a beginner or Debian. Look at some famous and widely supported distros. You will find Python pre-installed, too ;)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/160505)

Comment: Well, the thing is, I wouldn't use any of those two. I would get rid of ChromeOS immediately. That is why i didn't stand on them. But I see your point and I will keep that in mind. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

type in the terminal one of this "python", "python3" or "python -v". On the first two you will go to interactive mode, the latest will give you the version.
If you don't have a python interpreter, wich will be unusual, just `sudo apt-get install python python3"`. If don't use aptitude go for the package manager you like, or just build from source.