# How to install python on chromeos terminal

Tags: shell, python, chrome-os, chrome-book

In [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84160/running-python-on-chromeos/84167#84167) post, the top answer says that

> Alternatively you can go put your device in Developer Mode and gain access to a shell from where you can install/launch Python.

I want to know how to do this. Please note that I do not want to install crouton, just be able to run python in the shell.
Thanks.

Update: I found the command to install python. on [this](https://sites.google.com/site/chromeoswikisite/home/what-s-new-in-dev-and-beta/shell-acess-with-verified-boot) article near the bottom it says to use the command.

```
    dev_install
```

This installs a large amount of things straight into the console, including python.

Comment: Did you follow the link in the answer?

Comment: @Philippos there is no link that leads to what I want. I asked about installing python straight into the shell. this is mentioned, not explained and the two links in the answer only clarify what devloper mode and the shell are.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. somehow thought you asked how to go into the shell. So you made it to the shell but don't know how to install python? Maybe [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7Y8b2S3nEA) can help you?

Comment: That guide installs something. I know from experience that Python is one command away. There is a command that upgrades the terminal and Python 2.7 is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://sites.google.com/site/chromeoswikisite/home/what-s-new-in-dev-and-beta/shell-acess-with-verified-boot).

```
    dev_install
```

Comment: The link in this post is no good anymore, but you can get to the same page from the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20161213155647/https://sites.google.com/site/chromeoswikisite/home/what-s-new-in-dev-and-beta/shell-acess-with-verified-boot